# Error - Could not determine kind of name for C.Free - Golang

Tags: go

Espero que me puedan dar una ayuda. Estoy con un proyecto de Go que importa una librería C y que debe usar variables de tipo ***C.char**. Según entiendo, debo liberar manualmente la memoria una vez utilizada la variable. Implementé la función **C.free(unsafe.Pointer())** y obtengo el siguiente problema:

```
PS C:\Go-Project\src\GoEjemplos\Slice> go run slice-to-Cchar.go
# command-line-arguments
.\slice-to-Cchar.go:22:3: could not determine kind of name for C.Free
```

Este es el código con el que estoy probando la función.

```
package main

//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {

    slice := []string{"Tree", "Car", "Hotel", "Sun"}

    fmt.Println(slice)

    for _, v := range slice {
        var Cv *C.char = C.CString(v)

        fmt.Println(*Cv)

        C.Free(unsafe.Pointer(CvFixSta))
    }
}
```

Si elimino la función el código corre normalmente.

```
PS C:\Go-Project\src\GoEjemplos\Slice> go run slice-to-Cchar.go
[Tree Car Hotel Sun]
84
67
72
83
PS C:\Go-Project\src\GoEjemplos\Slice>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Cgo permite combinar en un único paquete funciones de C y de Go. Aunque el archivo sea "slice-to-Cchar.go" la función que intentas llamar es de C, por tanto se debe llamar utilizando la nomenclatura de C. Es decir, cambiar esto:

```
C.Free(unsafe.Pointer(CvFixSta))
```

por esto:

```
C.free(unsafe.Pointer(CvFixSta))
```